# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using scroll event

Tags: angular, universal, angular11

In my website, the logo rotate when user scroll in the page.

The code is very basic :

Component

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
scrollPos(){
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return Math.round(window.scrollY);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="assets/logo.svg" [ngStyle]="{ transform: 'rotate(' + scrollPos() + 'deg)' }" />
```

However, sometimes this basic code generate this error when navigating in the website :(

```
 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it 
 was checked. Previous value: 'rotate(397deg)'. Current value: 'rotate(331deg)'.
```

How can I update my above codes in order to avoid having this error?

thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally avoid returning things from `@HostListeners` because... they're not supposed to be called by anything but the events they listen to;

Instead, assign `window.scrollY` to a property in your component and access it from your component;

```
public wScrollY: number = 0;

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
scrollPos(){
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    this.wScrollY = Math.round(window.scrollY);
  }
}
```

Template

```
<img src="assets/logo.svg" [ngStyle]="{ transform: 'rotate(' + wScrollY + 'deg)' }" />
```

Comment: seems to work like a charm, thank you Mike !